# Simple char assignment not working in CUDA

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

Please look at the below code which does a simple char assignment

```
__global__ void seehowpointerwork(char* gpuHello, char* finalPoint){

    char* temp;
    bool found = false;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 11; i++){
        if(gpuHello[i] == ' '){
            temp = &gpuHello[i+1];
            found = true;

            break;
        }
    }
    bool sth = found;
    finalPoint = temp;

}
int main()
{
    // Testing one concept;
    string hello = "Hello World";
    char* gpuHello;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuHello, 11 * sizeof(char));
    cudaMemcpy(gpuHello, hello.c_str(), 11 * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    char* didItFind;
    char* whatIsIt = (char*)malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    seehowpointerwork<<<1,1>>>(gpuHello, didItFind);
    cudaMemcpy(whatIsIt,didItFind, 5 * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cout<<"The pointer points to : " << whatIsIt;
    return 0;
}
```

I really dont understand that when i print `whatIsIt`, why does it not print "World" as the answer but just prints some random string.

**EDIT**
Update version after accouting for null characters as pointed out

```
__global__ void seehowpointerwork(char* gpuHello, char* finalPoint){

    char* temp;
    bool found = false;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 11; i++){
        if(gpuHello[i] == ' '){
            temp = gpuHello;
            found = true;

            break;
        }
    }
    bool sth = found;
    finalPoint = temp;

}
int main()
{
    // Testing one concept;
    string hello = "Hello World";
    char* gpuHello;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuHello, 12 * sizeof(char));
    cudaMemcpy(gpuHello, hello.c_str(), 12 * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    char* didItFind;
    char* whatIsIt = (char*)malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
    seehowpointerwork<<<1,1>>>(gpuHello, didItFind);
    cudaMemcpy(whatIsIt,didItFind, 6 * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cout<<"The pointer points to : " << whatIsIt;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't allocated `didItFind`. Add some error checking and all will be revealed.

Comment: @talonmise: I dont want to allocate didItFind. It just points to a part of gpuHello, which is allocated.

Comment: Can you please tell me what type of error chcking are we talking about. I tried `cudaGetErrorString(cudaThreadSynchronize()));` but that does not work

Comment: Check the return value of the last `cudaMemcpy` and be prepared for an invalid argument error. `didItFind` cannot *ever* be a valid device pointer in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass `finalPoint` by reference, not by value if you want to have the kernel operate the way you have defined it. Perhaps something like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

__global__ void seehowpointerwork(char * gpuHello, char ** finalPoint){

    char* temp;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 11; i++){
        if(gpuHello[i] == ' '){
            temp = &gpuHello[i+1];
            break;
        }
    }
    *finalPoint = temp;
}

inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, 
                 bool abort=true)
{  
   if (code != cudaSuccess) {
      printf("GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

int main()
{
    string hello = "Hello World";
    char* gpuHello;
    gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuHello, 11 * sizeof(char)) );
    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(gpuHello, hello.data(), 11 * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );
    char ** didItFinda, * didItFindb;
    gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc((void **)&didItFinda, sizeof(char *)) );
    char* whatIsIt = (char*)malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    seehowpointerwork<<<1,1>>>(gpuHello, didItFinda);
    gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(&didItFindb, didItFinda, sizeof(char *), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(whatIsIt, didItFindb, 5 * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
    cout<<"The pointer points to : " << whatIsIt << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled and run, this version produces:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_12 -Xptxas="-v" programmer.cu 
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z17seehowpointerworkPcPS_' for 'sm_12'
ptxas info    : Used 4 registers, 8+16 bytes smem, 8 bytes cmem[1]

$ ./a.out 
The pointer points to : World
```

As it stands, the device to host copy will be failing, because `didItFind` is not a valid device pointer - you passed it by value to the kernel, so its value on the host cannot be modified by the kernel. The code above contains sufficient error checking to find this sort of problem - you should *always* check the return status of *every* API call.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer. But one final question: In my original code, in the kernel, will finalPoint point to "World" even though it is not reflected in didItFind

Comment: Thanks. Can you please help me with the other question about nsight i posted. Really would like to understand how to decipher the error information given by nsight. It should be easy to install and play with