# Warning while allocating CUDA device memory using C++ templates

Tags: templates, cuda, nvidia

I have declared the following template to make code shorter:

```
template <typename T>
void allocateGPUSpace(T* ptr, int size){

    cudaMalloc((void**)&ptr,size * sizeof(T));
}
```

Moreover, I use the template as follows:

`float* alphaWiMinusOne;`

`allocateGPUSpace<float>( alphaWiMinusOne,numUnigrams);`

However, when i compile the code, VS 2008 gives the warning

```
 warning: variable "alphaWiMinusOne" is used before its value is set
```

and

```
uninitialized local variable 'alphaWiMinusOne' used
```

Does cuda not understand templates in C++? Gosh, that will be a MUST do for nvidia

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, that warning doesn't come from CUDA, it comes from the host compiler (so Microsoft's C++ compiler or GCC depending on your platform), and it is a perfectly valid warning. You have made the same mistake you made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11487012/681865), and this code won't work as you are hoping, because you are passing the pointer to operate on by value, not by reference. Your code should be like this:

```
template <typename T> 
void allocateGPUSpace(T ** ptr, int size){   
    cudaMalloc((void**)ptr, size * sizeof(T)); 
}
```

and the call like this:

```
float * alphaWiMinusOne;
allocateGPUSpace<float>(&alphaWiMinusOne, numUnigrams);
```

or perhaps

```
template <typename T> 
T * allocateGPUSpace(int size){
    T * ptr;   
    cudaMalloc((void**)&ptr, size * sizeof(T));
    return ptr;
}
```

and then

```
float * alphaWiMinusOne = allocateGPUSpace<float>(numUnigrams);
```

Using either will eliminate the compiler warnings and the code will work. As a note of style, it would be a rather short sighted helper function design that didn't include any error checking.......